# Unity: 2D animator only playing first frame of animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I'm having a problem getting a death animation to play in full.

I have the animation set up correctly in the Unity animator with a bool isDead as a condition to change state from 'Any State' to 'Vampire Death'.

[image: Animator image]

The player character already has an attached Animator (and indeed plays the default flying animation just fine).

[image: Animator component attached]

I need to ensure the death animation plays in full before the rest of the logic within

```
//Game over on collision with obstacles
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
...
}
```

is called.

Here's my player controller script...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class VampireBatController : MonoBehaviour {

    //Declarations
    Rigidbody2D bat;
    public static int score;
    public static int finalScore;
    public static int highScore;
    public Text scoreText;
    public AudioClip flapSound;
    public AudioClip crashSound;
    public int batColliderIndex = 0;

    public Animator myAnimator;

    [SerializeField] private PolygonCollider2D[] colliders;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = 0;

        bat = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        myAnimator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Update score display
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        Debug.Log("SCORE: " + score);

        //Player input
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            bat.velocity = new Vector2(0, 4);
            SoundManager.instance.PlaySingle(flapSound);
        }
    }

    //Point increment function
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Point" && batColliderIndex == 9)
        {
            score++;
            return;
        }
    }

    //Game over on collision with obstacles
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag=="Skyscraper" || collision.gameObject.tag=="GroundCollider")
        {
            //Impact sound plays
            SoundManager.instance.PlaySingle(crashSound);

            //vampire_death animation plays
            //I wonder why only the first frame of the animation plays?
            myAnimator.SetBool("isDead", true);

            finalScore = score;
            Debug.Log("Game Over State Final Score: " + finalScore);

            if (score >= highScore)
            {
                highScore = score;
            }

            //Send highScore to PlayerPrefs
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("savedHighScore", highScore);
            Debug.Log("Game Over State HIGH SCORE: " + highScore);

            //Load game over screen
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            Debug.Log("Loading game over scene");
        }
    }

    //Sprite collider selector by animation frame
    public void SetColliderForSprite(int spriteNum)
    {
        colliders[batColliderIndex].enabled = false;
        batColliderIndex = spriteNum;
        colliders[batColliderIndex].enabled = true;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong or what I can do to ensure the animation plays fully before moving on to the rest of the game over state?

Comment: Since you editted your question, have you tried removing that logic from the OnCollisionEnter, placing it in a function then adding an animation event to your animation to call the function with that logic

Comment: Thanks for that. The animation now plays in full. However the new function playerDied() that I added (containing the previous game over state logic and added as an event to the last frame of the the animation) doesn't seem to be called.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.